# Looping over a valid JSON and save each value in variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm using jQuery.

This is my second post to make my old question more clear.
I have made an Ajax request using the `jQuery $.ajax function` to a PHP script and that PHP script returned this JSON object and when i tested with link text it says it's valid.
and i'm treating this JSON response with the `success fonction`

The php script is

```
$requete = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM annotations WHERE annot_doc_id = '$cours_selected' and annot_id_auteur  = '$annot_id_auteur'");
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($requete)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}
// echo '{"exemple":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The PHP is working very well and it's dynamicly changing the response according to my needs.
For a specific parametres i got this JSON response

```
[
{
    "id_annotation": "1",
    "annot_doc_id": "page_de_test.html",
    "annot_id_auteur": "2",
    "anno_startOffset": "47",
    "annot_startContainer": "id-aaa",
    "annot_endOffset": "88",
    "annot_forme": "1",
    "annot_value": "dispositif physique fait pour \n  stocker ",
    "annot_obj": "1",
    "annot_area": "",
    "annot_date": "vendredi 25 juin 2010 10:38:07" 
},
{
    "id_annotation": "4",
    "annot_doc_id": "page_de_test.html",
    "annot_id_auteur": "2",
    "anno_startOffset": "107",
    "annot_startContainer": "ident-77",
    "annot_endOffset": "194",
    "annot_forme": "1",
    "annot_value": "crobaties avec ses doigts, mais \u00e9cartons ce cas). Avec un \n  emplacement d\u2019information ",
    "annot_obj": "1",
    "annot_area": "",
    "annot_date": "vendredi 25 juin 2010 10:38:33" 
}
]
```

I want make a loop and save every time the "id_annotation", "annot_doc_id", "annot_id_auteur", "anno_startOffset" ....etc  in variables to do something with those variables.
How i can do that?

PS: some of you propsed the `$.each function.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop would for this:

```
var objects = $.parseJSON(input);
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { 
    alert(objects[i].id_annotation);
}
```

Or, if you wanted to usejQuery's `.each()` function:

```
var objects = $.parseJSON(input);
jQuery.each(objects, function() {
    alert(this.id_annotation);
});
```